# How do I remove this annoyingly pixelated popup?

Tags: unity, gnome, notification

How do I remove this annoyingly pixelated popup? It looks like the gnome3 popup for volume, however it only pops up when i use my laptops multimedia keys, not the volume or brightness keys. I can't figure out if it's a certain package (Which would be difficult considering unity also runs on gnome elements) anyone got an idea? [Here is an image](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/310706_447237418704572_1470577607_n.png)

[image]

Comment: In my case, something similar appears when I press the multimedia keys and the application i am using does not support them (VLC, play key). Which key do you press specifically? Also that happens always or only when using a specific app? The pixelated probably is caused by the theme you are using...

Comment: Audacious, VLC, Rhythmbox, with every key, play stop back forward. and i've tried with Elementary Dark, Ubuntu mono dark, and the theme i am currently using I'm just wondering why it's done a gnome 3 type popup, is that because of unity being on gnome elements or is it a conflict from a gnome3 package?

Comment: @user151356 I'm glade that you find the solution. Please, create a new answer instead of edit your question. That is how the site work. Is more useful than show it into the question. Thanks!

Comment: It won't let me post a new answer for another 4 hours, so until then i just placed it into the question, then when 4 hours is up ill post it as the answer and accept it :)

Comment: ok, but remember to create it! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved my own problem, I don't know how it worked, but I reinstalled ubuntu-desktop (This really isn't recommended because some extra packages were left missing for me to redownload myself) with

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove ubuntu-desktop*
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop unity-webapps-common
```

and rebooted.

**(As noted in the comments this is *NOT* recommended)**

Comment: Absolutely no idea why this worked, but *I **strongly** recommend against it* as it can (will) seriously mess with your packages.

Comment: well it worked without any other issues at all. How will it mess with your packages? The only package missing after the purge besides webapps was banshee which isn't even included as standard anymore...

Comment: As I said, I've absolutely no idea why it worked, but purging ubuntu-desktop* is a *bad* idea. Just my 2 cents.